# animate my div when we scroll & div come windows middle position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am need of a jquery/js functionality through which when user is scrolling the page and a certain div comes in middle position, then my div slowly fadeInUp . I don't expect exact but at least something to be nearest. when it scrollUp or scrolldown, both-time should be animated that div.

I can give animated effect but how window's middle position it will be happen , I can't . I am tired to trying .

My html code is here:

```
   <div class="vts">
        <div class="container top-cut-white">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="animatable fadeInUp">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h3>AGD Vehicle Tracking System (VTS)</h3>
                        <p>With AGD gps vehicle tracking and asset tracking your mobile workforce need never be out of sight or mind.</p>
                        <br>
                        <h3>Benefits of Vehicle Tracking</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span> Real-time visibility of your mobile workforce</li>
                            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span> Reduce fuel costs, mileage and emissions</li>
                            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span> Increase control of overtime costs</li>
                            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span> Boost productivity and workforce utilisation</li>
                            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span> Increase customer satisfaction through improved communication</li>
                            <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span> Obtain detailed insight to help drive your business forward efficiently</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="animatable fadeInUp">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <img src="img/agd_vts_software.png" class="img-responsive" alt="agdits">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

my css code is:

```
.animatable {
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}


/* show objects being animated */

.animated {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -ms-animation-duration: 1s;
    -o-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}
.animated.fadeInUp {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
    -moz-animation-name: fadeInUp;
    -o-animation-name: fadeInUp;
    animation-name: fadeInUp;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0.4;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
```

my js code is here:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {

        var doAnimations = function () {
            var offset = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height(),
                $animatables = $('.animatable');

            if ($animatables.size() == 0) {
                $(window).off('scroll', doAnimations);
            }
            $animatables.each(function (i) {
                var $animatable = $(this);
                if (($animatable.offset().top + $animatable.height() - 20) < offset) {
                    $animatable.removeClass('animatable').addClass('animated');
                }
            });

        };

        $(window).on('scroll', doAnimations);
        $(window).trigger('scroll');

    });
</script>
```

example given here.
I need , animation will happen when animated div come windows/page middle position

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help. An example that determines whether a DIV the middle of the screen:

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/msuv4hgc/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="middle"></div>
<div id="page">
    <div id="target"></div>   
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
    padding:0; margin:0;
}
#page{
    padding-top:400px;
    height:2280px;
    z-index:100;
}
#target,#middle{    
    background-color:red;
    height:50px; width:200px;
}
#middle{
    background-color:#000;
    position:fixed; top:400px; left:0;
    height:1px; width:100%;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var middle=0;
var deviation=5;
var $target;
var targetH=0;

$(function(){    
    $(window).scrollTop(200);//## fot test

    $target = $('#target');

    //## calculates the middle of the screen
    targetH = $target.height();    
    var windowH = $(window).height();
    middle= (windowH - targetH)/2;    

    $('#middle').css('top',middle);//## fot test

    //## on scroll event
    $( window ).scroll(function(){
        getPositon();
    })    
})

function getPositon()
{
    //## calculates the relative position of the target
    var topT = $target.offset().top;    
    var topW = $(window).scrollTop();
    var top = topT - topW;

    //## calculates the relative position of the target middle
    var middleT=top+targetH/2;

    var animate=false;//## fot test
    if(middleT + deviation > middle && middleT - deviation < middle)
    {   
        //########
        //ANIMATE
        //########
        animate=true;//## fot test
    }        
    $target.text('ANIMATION: '+animate);//## fot test

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to change `if` condition in your script to reflect your logic:

`$(window).scrollTop()` gives the current scroll position

`$(window).height()` will give you the the total height of window, so
`$(window).height()/2` will give you middle position of the window

so your logic should be: Animate `if $(window).scrollTop() > $(window).height()/2 and $(window).scrollTop() < $(window).height()/2`

But this fails as we cant get exact scroll position to be both greater and lesser than the current scoll position so try to take some offset length into consideration such as 20 or 10 or even 5 now your logic would be:

```
if($(window).scrollTop()-10 < $(window).height()/2 && $(window).scrollTop()+10 > $(window).height()/2)
```

So your JS code would be:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {

        var doAnimations = function () {
            var offset = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height(),
                $animatables = $('.animatable');

            if ($animatables.size() == 0) {
                $(window).off('scroll', doAnimations);
            }
            $animatables.each(function (i) {
                var $animatable = $(this);
                    if($(window).scrollTop()-15 < $(window).height()/2 && $(window).scrollTop()+15 > $(window).height()/2) {
                    $animatable.removeClass('animatable').addClass('animated');
                }
            });

        };

        $(window).on('scroll', doAnimations);
        $(window).trigger('scroll');

    });
</script>
```

Hope it helps.